# Can the "migrated" message on the "list" page indicate the place the message got migrated to? Instead of just "migrated"?

Tags: feature-request, migrated-questions

Can the "migrated" message on the "list" page indicate the place the message got migrated to? Instead of just "migrated"?

This would make it much easier to decide on whether to auto-go to the Stack Exchange site or not.

Comment: @Daniel, Sorry for my misunderstanding.  Comments deleted.